# Hash Table ConvertTo-Json PowerShell Formatting Issue

Tags: json, powershell, formatting, hashtable

I am using Hash Tables in PowerShell to get the data and than convert it to JSON. I am new to PS, so stuck with validating JSON. Here is my code:

```
################## intro
$userIntro = @{}
function getIntro {
    $userIntro.Add("first_name", "John") 
    $userIntro.Add("last_name", "Smith") 
    $userIntro.Add("age", "28") 
}
getIntro
$userIntro | ConvertTo-Json

################## address
$address = @{}
function getAddress {
    $address.Add("street", "21 2nd St") 
    $address.Add("city", "New York") 
    $address.Add("state", "NY") 
    $address.Add("zipcode", 12345) 
}
getAddress
$address | ConvertTo-Json
```

Out put of the code is this:

```
{
    "last_name":  "Smith",
    "age":  "28",
    "first_name":  "John"
}
{
    "street":  "21 2nd St",
    "state":  "NY",
    "zipcode":  12345,
    "city":  "New York"
}
```

As you can see, this is not valid JSON syntax because I am converting two separate objects and it's outputting accordingly.

However, what I am really trying to achieve is the the following... How can combine the objects into one conversion? and preferably add broken down to levels like this.

```
{
    "userIntro": {
        "last_name":  "Smith",
        "age":  "28",
        "first_name":  "John"
    },
    "address": {
        "street":  "21 2nd St",
        "state":  "NY",
        "zipcode":  12345,
        "city":  "New York"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need a hashtable that combines `$address` and `$userIntro` and then convert that to JSON:

```powershell
################## intro
$userIntro = @{}
function getIntro {
    $userIntro.Add("first_name", "John") 
    $userIntro.Add("last_name", "Smith") 
    $userIntro.Add("age", "28") 
}
getIntro
#$userIntro | ConvertTo-Json

################## address
$address = @{}
function getAddress {
    $address.Add("street", "21 2nd St") 
    $address.Add("city", "New York") 
    $address.Add("state", "NY") 
    $address.Add("zipcode", 12345) 
}
getAddress
#$address | ConvertTo-Json

$combined = @{}
$combined.Add("userIntro", $userIntro)
$combined.Add("address", $address)
$combined | ConvertTo-Json
```

outputs:

```powershell
{
    "address":  {
                    "zipcode":  12345,
                    "street":  "21 2nd St",
                    "city":  "New York",
                    "state":  "NY"
                },
    "userIntro":  {
                      "last_name":  "Smith",
                      "first_name":  "John",
                      "age":  "28"
                  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank @Scott Heaberlin